# error en "Url" ajax "url: '/',"

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc, url, sweetalert

Cuando se ejecuta el Javascript el Url es reemplazado por "url: '/'," por lo que me es imposible retornar los valores desde mi controlador hacia el script

alguien sabe cual es la causa de este problema?

Codigo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#logbtn').click(function (e) {
        var pin = $('#Pin').val();

        console.log(pin);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {Pin: pin},
        url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Ttraslados")',
        dataType: "json",
        success: (function (r) {
            console.log(r.Message);
            switch (r.Message) {
                case "Error1": swal("¡Cuidado!", "Este campo no puede estar vacio y el PIN solo deben ser numeros", "success"); break;
                case "Error2": swal("Oops!", "El usuario es incorrecto o inexistente", "error"); break;
                default: swal("Oops", "Error inesperado", "error");
            }
         }),
           error:(function () {
             swal("Oops", "Hubo un error", "error" );
         })
    });

        });
    });

</script>
```

y este es el codigo cuando se ejecuta

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#logbtn').click(function (e) {
        var pin = $('#Pin').val();

        console.log(pin);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {Pin: pin},
        url: '/',
        dataType: "json",
        success: (function (r) {
            console.log(r.Message);
            switch (r.Message) {
                case "Error1": swal("¡Cuidado!", "Este campo no puede estar vacio y el PIN solo deben ser numeros", "success"); break;
                case "Error2": swal("Oops!", "El usuario es incorrecto o inexistente", "error"); break;
                default: swal("Oops", "Error inesperado", "error");
            }
         }),
           error:(function () {
             swal("Oops", "Hubo un error", "error" );
         })
    });

        });
    });
```

la variable "url" almacena solo una slash.

copie este script de de otro que ya habia hecho que funciona correctamente

Comment: Copia el método que estas intentando llamar y en qué controlador esta

Comment: Lograste solucionar tu problema? Me interesaria saber porque te genera / y no la url.

Comment: Hola compañeros, sigo sin poder solucionar este problema, por mas que he estado investigando no encuentro algo que lo solucione :(